# how to upload pdf and image(any one whichever selected) file picked from phone via alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, image, pdf, upload, alamofire

This is the function calling on selecting the file. The parameters needs to be send. And the request url is the server url.

```
func Upload()
    { 
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constants.mainApi + 
        Constants.ADD_CLAIM_DOC)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(userToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: 
         "Authorization")

        let parameters = ["FileName": myURL as AnyObject,
                              "ClaimID":self.ClaimID!
                ] as [String : Any]
    }
```

Comment: I just fixed this and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

func UploadDoc(){

```
    let URL1 = URL(string: Constants.mainApi + Constants.ADD_CLAIM_DOC)!

    let filename = myURL?.lastPathComponent
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(self.myURL!, withName: filename)
            multipartFormData.append((self.ClaimID?.data(using: .utf8)!)!, withName: "ClaimID")

    },
        to: URL1,
        method : .post,
        headers : Constants.headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)


            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)

    })


}
```